# Clearing Toast Notifications in WinRT

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, toast

I have a Windows 8.1 application that is generating local toasts using `ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show()`

When run on Windows 10 this adds the notifications to the Action Centre.  Is there a way I can clear these notifications when my application starts?  I know the `ToastNotificationManager.History` approach isn't available as it's a Windows 8.1 app rather than Windows 10, but is there another way to achieve this?